# ExtJS 4.2.3 Grouping Bug

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I am using the store.group() to provide option to the user to group the grid by various fields.
Using extjs4.2.3 now after having faced many bugs in 4.2.1, store.group() does not seem to be working at all.
How to replicate:
Press the "Group" button, which should group the grid. Only sorts the data.
Choose "Group by this field" from the column menu and the grouping starts to work fine.

Similarly store.clearGrouping() behaves the same way.
Here is sample code:

```
    Ext.define('TestResult', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['student', 'subject', {
        name: 'mark',
        type: 'int'
    }]
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    width: 200,
    height: 240,
    itemId: 'gridtest',
    renderTo: document.body,
    features: [{
        groupHeaderTpl: 'Subject: {name}',
        ftype: 'groupingsummary'
    }],
    store: {
        model: 'TestResult',
        itemId: 'testStore',
        //groupField: 'subject',
        data: [{
            student: 'Student 1',
            subject: 'Math',
            mark: 84
        }, {
            student: 'Student 1',
            subject: 'Science',
            mark: 72
        }, {
            student: 'Student 2',
            subject: 'Math',
            mark: 96
        }, {
            student: 'Student 2',
            subject: 'Science',
            mark: 68
        }]
    },
    columns: [{
        dataIndex: 'student',
        text: 'Name',
        summaryType: 'count',
        summaryRenderer: function(value) {
            return Ext.String.format('{0} student{1}', value, value !== 1 ? 's' : '');
        }
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'mark',
        text: 'Mark',
        summaryType: 'average'
    }],
    tbar: [{
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'Group',
        handler: function(button, e) {
            var store = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gridtest')[0].getStore();
            store.group('subject');
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'button',
        text: 'clear',
        handler: function(button, e) {
            var store = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gridtest')[0].getStore();
            store.clearGrouping();
        }
    }]

});
```

Running the code in ExtJS 4.2.1 works fine on the sencha fiddle, but not on 4.2.3
I tested using the code preview option on http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/.

Answer (score 0):

Above code is working fine in extjs-4.2.3.

Open http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.3/ and in Developer tools Console tab execute following code:-
Group on 'Group' button is working fine.

```
Ext.define('TestResult', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  fields: ['student', 'subject', {
    name: 'mark',
    type: 'int'
  }]
});

var grpGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
  width: 200,
  height: 240,
  itemId: 'gridtest',
  renderTo: document.body,
  features: [{
    groupHeaderTpl: 'Subject: {name}',
    ftype: 'groupingsummary'
  }],
  store: {
    model: 'TestResult',
    itemId: 'testStore',
    //groupField: 'subject',
    data: [{
        student: 'Student 1',
        subject: 'Math',
        mark: 84
    }, {
        student: 'Student 1',
        subject: 'Science',
        mark: 72
    }, {
        student: 'Student 2',
        subject: 'Math',
        mark: 96
    }, {
        student: 'Student 2',
        subject: 'Science',
        mark: 68
    }]
  },
  columns: [{
    dataIndex: 'student',
    text: 'Name',
    summaryType: 'count',
    summaryRenderer: function(value) {
        return Ext.String.format('{0} student{1}', value, value !== 1 ? 's' : '');
    }
  }, {
    dataIndex: 'mark',
    text: 'Mark',
    summaryType: 'average'
  }],
  tbar: [{
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'Group',
    handler: function(button, e) {
        var store = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gridtest')[0].getStore();
        store.group('subject');
    }
  }, {
    xtype: 'button',
    text: 'clear',
    handler: function(button, e) {
        var store = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#gridtest')[0].getStore();
        store.clearGrouping();
    }
  }]

});

Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
  title: 'Hello',
  height: 200,
  width: 400,
  layout: 'fit',
  items: [grpGrid]
}).show();
```

Comment: May some issue with Sencha fiddle ext-4.2.3 version.

Comment: Hi Chetan, Can you elaborate more on how to run it on docs.sencha.com? I couldn't find a Developer tools Console tab

Comment: In Chrome browser press F12 to get Developer Tools, and in the console tab, copy and paste above code to execute it. You should see a floating Window with above grid and grouping working.

Comment: Hi Chetan, Thanks for this. Although it works by the method you described, in the application it does not. Sencha acknowledged the bug and the defect id is EXTJS-15190 [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?292166-Issues-with-stateful-grid-on-grouping&p=1067109)

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved in nightly build for ExtJS 4.2.4
Defect Id: EXTJS-15190 [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?292166-Issues-with-stateful-grid-on-grouping&p=1067109)